# w3wp/vs2010: Why do I have to attach w3wp.exe each time I need to debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, w3wp

Why do I have to attach w3wp.exe each time I need to debug?

When I execute my project I don't understand why I have each time I want to debug my project. When I stop VS2010 automatically dessasociate the process.

How can I fix the normal process when I stop execution process in debug mode doesn't stop process w3wp.exe

I am using IIS 7.

Thanks